# Generated group by a compact set is finitely generated

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, topological-groups, locally-compact-groups

Let $G$ be a locally compact group, and let $K\subseteq G$ be a compact set containing the identity. I want to make sure if the following statements are correct:

(i) Is it true that  $\langle K\rangle= \underset{m \in \mathbb{Z}}{\cup}K^m$?

(ii) Is it true that $\langle K\rangle$ is finitely generated?

(iii) Is $\langle K \rangle$ closed?

I have a suspicion that all three are true but am not sure.

The question stems from me trying to prove that a locally compact group has an open subgroup which is locally compact and $\sigma$-compact. I suspect $\langle K\rangle$ is the desired subpgroup.

These three points are questions which I am not sure on since I am a bit weak on group theory. I'm pretty sure the first one is true. The second and third are a 'hail mary', which I have not seen somewhere but suspect them to be true.

Comment: These are not questions from class, but facts I considered in showing the statement I've added in the edit. Be that as it may, I think these three statements are interesting for themselves, just for their possible implications. I have no further progress to show for them right now, but still think they merit a possible discussion.

Comment: What about $G = \mathbb{R}$ and $K = [0,1]$? In this example, your answers are: yes, no, yes.

Comment: This shows that (ii) is not correct. Do you think (i) and (iii) are correct?

Comment: You should take $K$ to have nonempty interior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find some flaws with the existing answer (**Now all are corrected**) so I post my own:

The answer to $(i)$ is a little complicated because you didn't define $K^n$ properly so I'll answer it below. The answer to $(ii),(iii)$ is no, even if $G$ is compact!

Counter-examples

(ii). Take $G=S^1$ (i.e. the unit circle, $S^1=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|=1\}$ with complex multiplication, and $K=G$.

(iii). Take $G=S^1$ and $K = \{1,\alpha\}$ where $\alpha\in S^1$ any element that is not a root of unity (i.e. there's no $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\alpha^n=1$). Then $\left<K\right>$ is dense and not closed.

For $(i)$ it really depends on how you define $K^n$.

Case 1: (**corrected**) it is false! (check out santana's answer)

Case 2: $K^n = \{k^n:k\in K\}$ in this case the answer is negative. Take $G=S^1$ and $K=\{1,e^{2\pi i\alpha},e^{2\pi i \beta}\}$ where $1,\alpha,\beta$ are independent over $\mathbb{Q}$. In this case the element $e^{2 \pi i (\alpha+\beta)}$ does not exist in $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} K^n$ as it's not a power of any element or an inverse of an element in $\{1,e^{2\pi i \alpha},e^{2\pi i \beta}\}$.

**ADDED**

> The question stems from me trying to prove that a locally compact group has an open subgroup which is locally compact and σ-compact. I suspect ⟨K⟩ is the desired subpgroup.

This is true if you choose $K$ correctly. If the set $K$ is the closure of a symmetric open set then the group $\left<K\right>$ is $\sigma$-compact (by $(i)$ if $K$ is symmetric) it is open (because it contains an open set, so $K=\bigcup_{k\in K} kU$) and hence it is also closed (any open subgroup is also closed, as it is the complement of it's non-trivial co-sets).

In other words if you choose a compact set $K$ which contains a neighborhood of the identity $1\in U \subseteq K$ (you can do that, because $G$ is locally compact) then $\left<K\right>$ is a closed $\sigma$-compact subgroup of $G$. If you understand my answer to your other questions above you can see that everything fails if $K$ does not contain an open neighborhood.

Comment: My thought when writing $K^n$ was the first case. Though if $K$ is not given to be symmetric, is it enough to take just the positive 'powers' of $K$?

Comment: @Keen-ameteur in that case I claim that $(i)$-holds. I realize that I contradict the previous answer, I believe they're mistaken ($-\frac{1}{3}$ should be an element in $K^{-1}$).

Comment: @Keen-ameteur about your edited comment  - that was my mistake for some reason I wrote $\mathbb{N}$ instead of $\mathbb{Z}$. Now it should be correct.

Comment: @Keen-ameteur I added something to my answer about your edited question. I think it'll be of a use for you.

Comment: Yanko, you're absolutely right about my example for (iii). I'm still unconvinced that, unless $K = K^{-1}$, the statement (i) holds in general.

Comment: @SantanaAfton I think you take the union only on positive integers, the union in the question is taken for $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. It includes the negative powers.

Comment: My characterization of $K^m$ as stated is wrong, but it is still true that $1/6\notin K^m$ for any $m$, positive or negative. I'll update.

Comment: @SantanaAfton Thanks, I edited my answer in response. You were right after all.

Answer (score 3):

All three of these are incorrect, as it turns out. Here are counterexamples. For all three, take $G = \mathbb{R}$.

1. Let $K = \{0,\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3}\}$. Note that $\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{3} = \frac{1}{6}\in\langle K\rangle$, but since

$$K^m = \left\{\frac{a}{2}+\frac{b}{3}: a,b\in\mathbb{Z},~\operatorname{sgn}(a) = \operatorname{sgn}(b), ~|a+b|\le m\right\}$$

there is no $m$ such that $\frac{1}{6}\in K^m$.

2. Let $K = [0,1]$. Since any real number is some integer multiple of some $k\in K$, we have $\langle K\rangle = G$. However, $G$ is not finitely generated.
3. [See Yanko's answer for a good counterexample here.]

Comment: Your argument for (i) is not correct unless $K^{-1} = K$. Why should $k_1 k_2^{-1}$ be contained in some $K^m$?

Comment: @PaulFrost Yeah, I just realized that I’m definitely wrong. I was assuming $K^m$ was words of length $m$, not what it actually is. There should be an easy counterexample here. I’ll edit my answer when I find it.

Comment: Consider $G = \mathbb{Z}^2$ and $K = \{ (0,0), (0,1), (1,0) \}$.

Comment: You forgot $0 \in K$. Hence $K^m = \{ \frac{a}{2} + \frac{b}{3} \mid a,b \ge 0, a + b \le m \}$. But certainly  $\frac{1}{6} \notin K^m$. By the way, $K = \{0, 2, 3 \}$ works also.

Comment: @PaulFrost Thanks! Today must not be my day. Adding $0$ to $K$ shouldn't change my statement about the union though -- is that correct? In this abelian case, $K^m = mK$.

Comment: $K^m = mK$ is in general wrong. Take $K = \{0, 2, 3 \}$. Then $K^m = \{0, 2, 3,\dots,3m-1, 3m \}$.

Comment: Hm. Perhaps I don't even know the definition of $K^m$. Is it not $\{k^m: k\in K\}$?

Comment: I think $K^m$ is the set of all products $k_1 \dots k_m$ withj $k_i \in K$. More generally, $A B$ is the set of all products $a b$ with $a \in A, b \in B$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90575/discussion-between-santana-afton-and-paul-frost).

Comment: Please see my answer. To the best of my knowledge $\mathbb{Z}$ **is closed** in $\mathbb{R}$. Also I think you're mistaken about $(i)$.